# How to add application in google play for private channel

Tags: android

I want share my android application for private channel, I read [docs](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=ru&hlrm=en&answer=2494992) -, try to add application to google play with corporate email, but I didn't see, where in google play I should choose between private and public channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Preview version of the Developer Console does not support the Private channel yet. I used the old version of the Developer Console to publish apps to a Private channel for the time being.